# Error in trying to pass Struct pointer to class

Tags: c++

I am working on a game where I am currently trying to make a player struct to store player information such as name for example. I would like to make a class to divide the code segments for cleaner code in my main.cpp.

I have my struct:

```
   //in main.cpp
 #include "player.h"
class MyClass player
    struct _Player {
        std::string name;
        int hp;
        int mana;
        int def;
        int mana_regen;
        int hp_regen;
    } player1;

void playerinfo2(_Player *playerx) {
    playerx->name = "test2";
}

int main() {
    player1.name = "test1";
    std::cout << player1.name << std::endl;
    playerinfo2(&player1);
    std::cout << player1.name;
    player.playerinfo(&player1);
}
```

This code is working and is changing the name of player1 from "test1" to "test2".

```
//in player.h   
class MyClass {

struct _Player {
    std::string name;
    int hp;
    int mana;
    int def;
    int mana_regen;
    int hp_regen;
};
public:

void player_update();
void playerinfo(_Player *self);

private:

};
```

I dont know if the struct needs to exist both in the header and in the .cpp file but it says "unknown _Player" if I do not.

```
//in player.cpp
#include "player.h"

struct _Player {
    std::string name;
    int hp;
    int mana;
    int def;
    int mana_regen;
    int hp_regen;
};

void Player::player_update() {
    playery.mana = playery.mana + playery.mana_regen;

}

void Player::playerinfo(_Player *self) {
    self->name = "test3";
}
```

When running in console g++ main.cpp player.cpp -o test.exe I receive the error message:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:29:29: error: no matching function for call to 'Player::playerinfo(_Player*)'
     test.playerinfo(&player1);
                             ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
player.h:21:6: note: candidate: void Player::playerinfo(Player::_Player*)
 void playerinfo(_Player *self);
      ^~~~~~~~~~
player.h:21:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '_Player*' to 'Player::_Player*'
```

Is there any way I can pass my player1 to the class like I am doing with my function in main.cpp?

Comment: You have the same struct defined in three different places. It should be in only one place in a header file.

Comment: @interjay, yes removing the struct from player.cpp is working but if I am using the struct in main.cpp I need to declare it there aswell?

Comment: If you haven't gotten any good books to read yet, [here's a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). Please get a couple of them and read *from the bginning*. It seems to me like you're just guessing about how C++ work, and that's not a good way to learn *any* language (programming or other).

Comment: `struct _Player` That identifier is reserved. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another name for the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by renaming my class to an unused name, put the struct only in player.h, declared player1 in main.cpp and then sent player1 as I did to send it to the playerinfo2 function.

```
//in main.cpp
#include "player.h"

class MyClass test;


userPlayer player1;

void playerinfo2(userPlayer *self) {
    self->name = "test1";
}

int main() {
    playerinfo2(&player1);
    std::cout << player1.name;
    test.playerinfo(&player1);
    std::cout << player1.name;

}


//in player.h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct userPlayer {
    std::string name;
    int hp;
    int mana;
    int def;
    int mana_regen;
    int hp_regen;
};

class MyClass {

public:

void player_update();
void playerinfo(userPlayer *self);

private:

};

//in player.cpp
#include "player.h"


void MyClass::playerinfo(userPlayer *self) {
    self->name = "test3";
}
```

This updated code is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

No you need to define class only once in header file(say player.h) and use `#include player.h` in all files that are class. If you have any function for player class it is a convention you declare them in header file and define them in `.cpp` file. You could also declare and define them in header file and avoid `.cpp` file but it can cause messy code.